# How to bind VS code actions to vim commands in VSCodeVim?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

How can I bind VS code actions like `workbench.action.toggleActivityBarVisibility` to make new vim commands like `:tglActivityBar`. Here is what I tried in my vscode's `settings.json`:

```
"vim.normalModeKeyBindings": [
    {
        "before": [":tglActivityBar"],
        "commands": [
            "workbench.action.toggleActivityBarVisibility",
        ]
    }
```

It doesn't work.

I'm using [VSCodeVim](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim) extension for VS code